# javascript window.print() internet explorer 8 not printing entire webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

When printing from windows7 with ie8; only whats visible in viewport is printing. 
Printing from windows8 which I believe has ie9 prints the whole webpage with no issue, about 5 pages in total. It will work with compatibly view enabled though.

All is checked from the print prompt so that's not an issue. This was brought to my attention from a user so its not an isolated issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page or a screenshot? My first guess is that what needs to be printed is within a div with `overflow: scroll` content, but I can't be certain without seeing the page.

Comment: CoryDanielson. no its on our dev server. No divs, I've dealt with that before and there are no divs or overflow settings. Most data is organized within tables. the tables have no height attributes but do have set widths, usually by percent. this occurs whenever the data exceeds one print page, so the print cuts off after one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the body to static

body{position: static;}